# How to rename a database with ASP.NET Core 2.2?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, connection-string

I used code first migrations with EF Core to create my database. Unfortunately it was automatically named this weird long name "aspnet-Gym.Ui-7BF4FA98-38C4-462F-B491-35AA9FB65339". 
This is the connection string from appsettings.json:

```
"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=aspnet-Gym.Ui-7BF4FA98-38C4-462F-B491-35AA9FB65339;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

How to change the name to "MyDatabase"?

Do I need to add something to this string, add a new migration and update the database via Package Manager Console?

Edit:

@KirkLarkin 's explanation solved my issue:

1) Drop-Database in Package Manager Console,

2) Update the connection-string in appsettings.json -> change the value of Initial Catalog to MyDatabase (Initial Catalog=MyDatabase)

3) Update-Database in Package Manager Console

Comment: You can just drop the existing database, change the value of `Initial Catalog` to `MyDatabase` (`Initial Catalog=MyDatabase`) and then recreate the database.

Comment: What did you put in your ConnectionString in the appsettings json?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Drop it from SQL Server or Visual Studio?
William, I wrote the entire Connection string in the question above.

Comment: @KirkLarkin with Update-Database - with the Package Manager Console.

Comment: I think it should be 1) `Drop-Database` 2) Update the connection-string as I said above 3) `Update-Database`

Comment: @KirkLarkin this worked but now I can't see the database under SQL Server Object Explorer(Visual studio)